# Why can't I use autoproxy argument in eclipse's ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

version info in eclipse:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
```

help info in eclipse:

```
no autoproxy argument
```

But when I use ant in the command-line,there is autoproxy argument.

```
help info in command-line(ant 1.9.4):
  -autoproxy             Java1.5+: use the OS proxy settings
```

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Platform Ant Project [exists independent of Eclipse as an Apache open source project](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/ant/) and thus may not be feature-for-feature identical to the Ant command line.

(There is a small irony here, as the instructions for building Eclipse locally require you to run Ant from the command line with the -autoproxy option.)

You might be able to get things to work with the `<setproxy/>` Task, though I don't think this groks autoproxies.

You might be able to solve this by setting `java.net.useSystemProxies` (which is all -autoproxy does, I understand) on the VM running Ant, or by setting `-autoproxy` via the `ANT_ARGS` environment variable. The latter is, I admit, hand-waving, as I have never added environment to tweak a plugin within Eclipse.